# how to get some filtered results from class based views in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.

class LiveClass(models.Model):
    standard = models.IntegerField()
    no_of_students_registered = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Class'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.standard) + ' class'

class User_details(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, max_length=30)
    standard = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'User_details'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Mentor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    details = models.TextField()
    ratings = models.FloatField(default=2.5)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Mentors'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class LiveClass_details(models.Model):
    standard = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapter_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    chapter_details = models.TextField()
    mentor_name = models.ForeignKey(Mentor, max_length=30, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    isDoubtClass = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    doubtsAddressed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'LiveClass_details'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.chapter_name



class SavedClass(models.Model):
    class_details = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ForeignKey(User_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_registered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_attended = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta: 
         verbose_name_plural = 'SavedClasses'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'SavedClass : ' + str(self.class_details)
```

**my serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models



class LiveClass_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LiveClass
        fields = '__all__'


class User_details_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User_details
        fields = '__all__'


class LiveClass_details_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LiveClass_details
        fields = '__all__'

class Mentor_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Mentor
        fields = '__all__'

class SavedClass_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.SavedClass
        fields = '__all__'
```

**my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.response import Response


from . import serializers
from . import models
# Create your views here.

class ListLiveClass(mixins.ListModelMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.LiveClass_details.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.LiveClass_details_serializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

class LiveClassView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    LoginRequiredMixin,
                    generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.LiveClass_details.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.LiveClass_details_serializer
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

class LiveClassViewId(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                    LoginRequiredMixin,
                    generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.LiveClass_details.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.LiveClass_details_serializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get(self, request, id=None, format=None):
        if id:
           return self.retrieve(request)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def put(self, request, id, format=None):

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.update(request, id)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

    def delete(self, request, id, format=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.destroy(request, id)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)


class ListMentors(mixins.ListModelMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.Mentor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.Mentor_serializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)



class ListUserDetails(mixins.ListModelMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.User_details.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.User_details_serializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)



#api endpoints to save  and register live classes 

class SavedClassView(LoginRequiredMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    model = models.SavedClass
    serializer = serializers.SavedClass_serializer
    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.id
    
    def get(self, request):
        CurrentUserID = self.get_object()
```

**In SavedClassView i want to get saved classes from the current logged user only and i want to preserve this user from getting other user saved classes , i have done something like above but i am getting no perfect logic that fits the working of django rest framework , please help me in achieving the above result**

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add filter to queryset

queryset = models.User_details.objects.filter(user=request.user)

Just make sure to implement tokens so you can access request.user

Comment: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `class_details` on serializer `SavedClass_serializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User_details` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User_details' object has no attribute 'class_details'.

Comment: **I am  getting error like this when i used query set of **                                               
   `def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return models.User_details.objects.filter(name = user)`

Comment: It is now querying on User details object but i want to query it on SavedClass object by filtering only the current user